# I am facing android.view.InflateException when I put a specific imageView in my code

Tags: android, android-layout, user-interface

I have set an image asset icon just for UI needs but it shows error. I checked if image is proper and it is proper and has size of 1 kb. I am unable to find out what's the problem here. Here's my error image code:

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/arrow_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_5sdp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_expand_more_24"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.802"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />
```

Here's whole error log as shown in logcat:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.gtappdevelopers.gfgroomdatabase, PID: 24472
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.gtappdevelopers.gfgroomdatabase/com.gtappdevelopers.gfgroomdatabase.NewCourseActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #421: Binary XML file line #421: Error inflating class ImageButton
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2423)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2483)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:153)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1349)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5441)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:738)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:628)
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #421: Binary XML file line #421: Error inflating class ImageButton
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:543)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:427)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:699)
at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:195)
at com.gtappdevelopers.gfgroomdatabase.NewCourseActivity.onCreate(NewCourseActivity.java:117)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6303)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1108)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2376)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2483) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:153) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1349) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5441) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:738) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:628) 
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #421: Error inflating class ImageButton
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:786)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:708)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:839)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:802)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:842)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:802)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:842)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:802)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:842)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:802)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:842)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:802)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:842)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:802)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:842)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:802)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:519)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:427) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:699) 
at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:195) 
at com.gtappdevelopers.gfgroomdatabase.NewCourseActivity.onCreate(NewCourseActivity.java:117) 
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6303) 
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1108) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2376) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2483) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:153) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1349) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5441) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:738) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:628) 
Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f08006c
at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1369)
at android.content.res.MiuiResources.getValue(MiuiResources.java:145)
at androidx.appcompat.widget.ResourceManagerInternal.loadDrawableFromDelegates(ResourceManagerInternal.java:255)
at androidx.appcompat.widget.ResourceManagerInternal.getDrawable(ResourceManagerInternal.java:142)
at androidx.appcompat.widget.ResourceManagerInternal.getDrawable(ResourceManagerInternal.java:135)
at androidx.appcompat.content.res.AppCompatResources.getDrawable(AppCompatResources.java:104)
at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageHelper.loadFromAttributes(AppCompatImageHelper.java:63)
at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageButton.<init>(AppCompatImageButton.java:83)
at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageButton.<init>(AppCompatImageButton.ja
```

I was expecting the app to wrok fine but it shows this error.

Comment: have tried invalidate cache the project ?

Comment: yes but it did not make any difference

Comment: make sure that ic_baseline_expand_more_24 is in the drawable folder not drawable-???

Answer (score 0):

If you look toward the bottom of the stack trace, you will see the following line:

> Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f08006c

A resource with the resource ID of `#0x7f08006c` was not found. Since the package of the id is `7f`, this is a resource that you have created. (Android resource package code is `0x01`.)

You have correctly identified the source of the problem as the *ImageButton* because we see earlier in the trace the following:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.gtappdevelopers.gfgroomdatabase/com.gtappdevelopers.gfgroomdatabase.NewCourseActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #421: Binary XML file line #421: Error inflating class ImageButton

So, it looks like the drawable is missing. You can get the name of the drawable from [Resources#getResourceName(int)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources#getResourceName(int)) although it will undoubtedly be `drawable/ic_baseline_expand_more_24` assuming that you have identified the right *ImageButton*.

Check your base drawable folder to make sure the drawable is defined there as a fallback.